Boto3 and Pandas causing error on AWS Lambda
I'm using Python 3.9 with boto3, pandas==1.5.3 and pandera==0.8.1.
In my requirements.txt I install pandas and pandera.
My code is very simple, not finished yet, but I need Pandas and s3 client, when I run locally, it works:
import faulthandler
import pandas as pd
import boto3

faulthandler.enable()


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

    # Not implemented yet

    return {"status_code": 200}


Running on the following image:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9

COPY src/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

COPY requirements/requirements.txt  .

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"

CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]

But running the Lambda Function on AWS, I get the error:
Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: segmentation fault
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173 in create_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565 in module_from_spec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py", line 23 in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1058 in _handle_fromlist
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 36 in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/compat.py", line 94 in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "/var/runtime/s3transfer/__init__.py", line 143 in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 131 in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "/var/runtime/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 18 in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228 in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850 in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680 in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986 in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007 in _find_and_load
File "/var/runtime/boto3/utils.py", line 56 in import_module
File "/var/runtime/boto3/utils.py", line 65 in _handler
File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 239 in _emit
File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 256 in emit
File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 412 in emit
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 201 in _create_client_class
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 147 in create_client
File "/var/runtime/botocore/session.py", line 997 in create_client
File "/var/runtime/boto3/session.py", line 299 in client
File "/var/runtime/boto3/__init__.py", line 92 in client
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 21 in lambda_handler
File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 188 in handle_event_request
File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/bootstrap.py", line 499 in run
File "/var/runtime/awslambdaric/__main__.py", line 21 in main
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 57 in main
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 60 in <module>

When I don't have the pandas import, the code works.
I have tried change the Python, Pandas and boto3 version.
I configured my lambda with max memory:
Lambda Configuration
The lambda policy has permission to entire s3.

Are you expecting the public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9 image to include pandas?

No, in my requirements I install pandas

You have to install requirements as part of the Docker build. I don't know if your src directory contains the requirements as installed on the build machine, but you can't do that if yes.

Finally I discover. In my requirements file, I have pandas==1.5.3 and I also have pandera==0.8.1, I don't know why, but when I update pandera to 0.19.2, it works.
